# How to Fix Union Command in Access

Tags: sql, ms-access, union

I have Two Queries where I am using Expressions to Count when a Specific Word is selected. Both queries work as intended but I want to combine them using Union Query. The union works but when the Rep name is in both queries it lists the name twice.

When I run my Union I receive the following

```
Rep     OppCount    DevCount    BiddingCount
Darrell    0            0           0
Josh       40           7           156
Kyle       0            0           15
Leah       26           4           55
Mark       59           8           159
Vic        25           2           191
Darrell    0            94          0
Josh       0            51          0
Kyle       0            62          0
Leah       0            101         0
Mark       0            87          1
Vic        0            8           0
```

```
SELECT Opp_New.Rep AS Rep, "" AS FaceToFaceCount, "" AS PhoneCount, "" AS EmailCount, Sum(IIf([Opp_New]![Status]="Opportunity",1,0)) AS OppCount, Sum(IIf([Opp_New]![Status]="Developing",1,0)) AS DevCount, Sum(IIf([Opp_New]![Status]="Bidding",1,0)) AS BiddingCount, Sum(IIf([Opp_New]![Status]="At MFG for Quote",1,0)) AS AtMFGCount, Sum(IIf([Opp_New]![Status]="Did Not Bid",1,0)) AS DNBCount, Sum(IIf([Opp_New]![Status]="Bid/Quote",1,0)) AS QuotedCount, Sum(IIf([Opp_New]![Status]="Won",1,0)) AS WonCount, Sum(IIf([Opp_New]![Status]="Lost",1,0)) AS LostCount
FROM Opp_New
GROUP BY Rep

UNION ALL

SELECT Calls_New.Rep AS Rep, Sum(IIf([Calls_New]![ContactType]="Face To Face",1,0)) AS FaceToFaceCount, Sum(IIf([Calls_New]![ContactType]="Phone",1,0)) AS PhoneCount, Sum(IIf([Calls_New]![ContactType]="Email",1,0)) AS EmailCount, Sum(IIf([Calls_New]![ProjectStatus]="Opportunity",1,0)) AS OppCount, Sum(IIf([Calls_New]![ProjectStatus]="Developing",1,0)) AS DevCount, Sum(IIf([Calls_New]![ProjectStatus]="Bidding",1,0)) AS BiddingCount, Sum(IIf([Calls_New]![ProjectStatus]="At MFG for Quote",1,0)) AS AtMFGCount, Sum(IIf([Calls_New]![ProjectStatus]="Did Not Bid",1,0)) AS DNBCount, Sum(IIf([Calls_New]![ProjectStatus]="Bid/Quote",1,0)) AS QuotedCount, Sum(IIf([Calls_New]![ProjectStatus]="Won",1,0)) AS WonCount, Sum(IIf([Calls_New]![ProjectStatus]="Lost",1,0)) AS LostCount
FROM Calls_New
GROUP BY Rep
```

I am wanting to union like the following

```
Rep     OppCount    DevCount    BiddingCount
Darrell     0           94          0
Josh        40          58          156
Kyle        0           62          15
Leah        26          105         55
Mark        59          95          160
Vic         25          10          191
```

Comment: Aggregate your UNION of two aggregate queries or UNION the tables first and aggregate that dataset.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks to me you don't want to use a `UNION` at all, but an `INNER JOIN` on `rep` instead.

```
SELECT t1.Rep, t1.OppCount + t2.OppCount As OppCount, t1.BiddingCount + t2.BiddingCount As BiddingCount
FROM (
    SELECT Opp_New.Rep AS Rep, "" AS FaceToFaceCount, "" AS PhoneCount, "" AS EmailCount, Sum(IIf([Opp_New]![Status]="Opportunity",1,0)) AS OppCount, Sum(IIf([Opp_New]![Status]="Developing",1,0)) AS DevCount, Sum(IIf([Opp_New]![Status]="Bidding",1,0)) AS BiddingCount, Sum(IIf([Opp_New]![Status]="At MFG for Quote",1,0)) AS AtMFGCount, Sum(IIf([Opp_New]![Status]="Did Not Bid",1,0)) AS DNBCount, Sum(IIf([Opp_New]![Status]="Bid/Quote",1,0)) AS QuotedCount, Sum(IIf([Opp_New]![Status]="Won",1,0)) AS WonCount, Sum(IIf([Opp_New]![Status]="Lost",1,0)) AS LostCount
    FROM Opp_New
    GROUP BY Rep
) t1
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT Calls_New.Rep AS Rep, Sum(IIf([Calls_New]![ContactType]="Face To Face",1,0)) AS FaceToFaceCount, Sum(IIf([Calls_New]![ContactType]="Phone",1,0)) AS PhoneCount, Sum(IIf([Calls_New]![ContactType]="Email",1,0)) AS EmailCount, Sum(IIf([Calls_New]![ProjectStatus]="Opportunity",1,0)) AS OppCount, Sum(IIf([Calls_New]![ProjectStatus]="Developing",1,0)) AS DevCount, Sum(IIf([Calls_New]![ProjectStatus]="Bidding",1,0)) AS BiddingCount, Sum(IIf([Calls_New]![ProjectStatus]="At MFG for Quote",1,0)) AS AtMFGCount, Sum(IIf([Calls_New]![ProjectStatus]="Did Not Bid",1,0)) AS DNBCount, Sum(IIf([Calls_New]![ProjectStatus]="Bid/Quote",1,0)) AS QuotedCount, Sum(IIf([Calls_New]![ProjectStatus]="Won",1,0)) AS WonCount, Sum(IIf([Calls_New]![ProjectStatus]="Lost",1,0)) AS LostCount
    FROM Calls_New
    GROUP BY Rep
) t2 ON t1.Rep = t2.Rep
```

Of course, when using the `INNER JOIN`, you can scrape stuf, like the empty FaceToFaceCount, PhoneCount and EmailCount from the first query, and just don't add those. Since you excluded them from your sample output I haven't included them in the outer query but it should be easy enough to adjust.

Comment: Thank you this works. I only posted a few columns of the table outputs so I will work on adding the rest.

Answer (score 0):

Just aggregate your result columns by `sum()` function

```
SELECT Rep,  
       sum(OppCount) as OppCount,  
       sum(DevCount) as DevCount, 
       sum(BiddingCount) as BiddingCount
 FROM 
(
   SELECT Opp_New.Rep AS Rep, "" AS FaceToFaceCount, "" AS PhoneCount, "" AS EmailCount, Sum(IIf([Opp_New]![Status]="Opportunity",1,0)) AS OppCount, Sum(IIf([Opp_New]![Status]="Developing",1,0)) AS DevCount, Sum(IIf([Opp_New]![Status]="Bidding",1,0)) AS BiddingCount, Sum(IIf([Opp_New]![Status]="At MFG for Quote",1,0)) AS AtMFGCount, Sum(IIf([Opp_New]![Status]="Did Not Bid",1,0)) AS DNBCount, Sum(IIf([Opp_New]![Status]="Bid/Quote",1,0)) AS QuotedCount, Sum(IIf([Opp_New]![Status]="Won",1,0)) AS WonCount, Sum(IIf([Opp_New]![Status]="Lost",1,0)) AS LostCount
     FROM Opp_New
    GROUP BY Rep    
    UNION ALL    
   SELECT Calls_New.Rep AS Rep, Sum(IIf([Calls_New]![ContactType]="Face To Face",1,0)) AS FaceToFaceCount, Sum(IIf([Calls_New]![ContactType]="Phone",1,0)) AS PhoneCount, Sum(IIf([Calls_New]![ContactType]="Email",1,0)) AS EmailCount, Sum(IIf([Calls_New]![ProjectStatus]="Opportunity",1,0)) AS OppCount, Sum(IIf([Calls_New]![ProjectStatus]="Developing",1,0)) AS DevCount, Sum(IIf([Calls_New]![ProjectStatus]="Bidding",1,0)) AS BiddingCount, Sum(IIf([Calls_New]![ProjectStatus]="At MFG for Quote",1,0)) AS AtMFGCount, Sum(IIf([Calls_New]![ProjectStatus]="Did Not Bid",1,0)) AS DNBCount, Sum(IIf([Calls_New]![ProjectStatus]="Bid/Quote",1,0)) AS QuotedCount, Sum(IIf([Calls_New]![ProjectStatus]="Won",1,0)) AS WonCount, Sum(IIf([Calls_New]![ProjectStatus]="Lost",1,0)) AS LostCount
     FROM Calls_New
    GROUP BY Rep
) q
GROUP BY Rep
```

Comment: Thank you, I will try this.